# Laravel Email Verification Process

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer, web-development-server

I am trying to set up the email verification with Laravel 7.x on our live server and getting some issues connecting. So, I can run simple Swift code along these lines:

```
  try {     
            // Create the SMTP transport
            $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('my-mail-relay.something.ca'));
            $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
            // Create a message
            $message = new Swift_Message();
            $message->setSubject('Test!');
            $message->setFrom(['my@email.com' => 'tom']);
            $message->addTo('test@email.com', 'test');
            // Set the plain-text part
            $message->setBody('Test.');
            // Set the HTML part
            $message->addPart('Test<br>TEST.', 'text/html');
            // Send the message
            $result = $mailer->send($message);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

This results in the email being sent properly through the smtp server etc. However when I set all the same parameters in .env and config/mail.php I always timeout, I've tried removing the need for a port internally in laravel's mail service but (perhaps obviously) receive other errors that way.

In the mean time I've set up sendmail on our server and tried to set the smtp server in the /etc/mail/sendmail.mc, now it sends the emails but they invariably end up in spam, whereas when sending them through the smtp server using the above code it works fine.

.env, not that there's much to show:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
#MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST= *******************
# MAIL_USERNAME= ************
# MAIL_PASSWORD= ******************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=************
MAIL_FROM_NAME=*************
```

mail.php :

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', '**********'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        ... etc

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', '***********'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        ],
    ],
```

Anyone have any experience setting this up properly that could point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Thom